How do I enter a bigint number in SSIS?
This is a cross-site duplicate of Evaluate Expression with expression builder - Stack Overflow, I wanted to share this with screenshots and with a broader question since you hit the other link only if you search for the errors. Thanks go to the answer there.
I try adding a bigint column as a new derived column, which throws the errors:
Error1:

The literal "12345678910" is too large to fit into type DT_I4. The magnitude of the literal overflows the type.

Error2:

Attempt to parse the expression "(DT_I8)12345678910"failed and returned error code 0xC004707C. The expression cannot be parsed. It might contain invalid elements or it might not be well-formed. There may also be an out-of-memory error.


Question
How do I enter a bigint number in SSIS?
Legend
DT_I8 = 8-bytes Integer
DT_I4 = 4-bytes Integer

Add an L at the end of the number.

There is no need to write (DT_I8)12345678910L, 12345678910L is enough, checked in the metadata right after the box:

